# how do I store my prompt input and display all of it when I input zero

Tags: javascript, prompt

```
let i = -1;
let total = 0;
let numPrompt;

do {
  numPrompt = prompt("")
  total += parseInt(numPrompt)
  i++;
} 
  
while (numPrompt != '0');  // do-while loop 

let avg = total/i;
console.log(total)
console.log(avg)
```

I want user to input a number each time till they input zero which will output all their previous input, total and average.

I declare i = -1 to avoid counting the last input which is the zero.

in my code, I only manage to display the total of all my input but what I also want is all my previous inputs (prompt)printed out each row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array, which stores a list of things:

```js
let i = 0;
let total = 0;
let numPrompt;
let numbers = [];

do {
    numPrompt = prompt("")
    total += parseInt(numPrompt)
    if (numPrompt != '0') {
        numbers.push(numPrompt);
        i++;
    }
} while (numPrompt != '0'); // do-while loop 

let avg = total / i;
console.log(total)
console.log(avg)
console.log(numbers);
```

Setting `i` to -1 is a bit of a workaround -- the above code starts it at 0 and checks if the inputted number is 0 before incrementing it.

Comment: what should i do if I want it to be 
1 (one line)
2 (one line)
3 (one line)
rather than [1, 2, 3].
for the output of the (numbers)

Comment: here are two ways you can do it: `console.log(numbers.join('\n'))`, which joins the list on a newline character, or in a loop `for (var j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) { console.log(numbers[j]); }`, which prints out each number one at a time

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store all of your previous inputs, use an array.

```js
let a=[], i, t;
while((i=+prompt())!==0) a.push(i);
console.log(`inputs: ${a}, total: ${t=a.reduce((a,c)=>a+c)}, avg: ${t/a.length}`);
```